# Efficient data structure for storing nongrammatical strings

Tags: data-structures

I need a data structure in which I can store object of variable size and later modify its bytes or remove it, but not change its size (that would be done only be removing it and reinserting with new size). Objects do not need random access, only sequential. I need its memory-efficiency to approach 1 as the total memory allocated approaches infinity (assuming all pointers magically require a constant space and we won't be questioning that).

I do know for tries and that it's popular for storing strings, but after all my needs trie is just not what I am looking for. After all, my strings will not have "common" morphemes, they will be technical and pseudo-random. I am not storing words.

Another option I came to is to have a magic constant `M` and then `M` vectors where k-th vector stores chunks of k bytes and one pointer which points to another chunk (a previous block in the following context). Additionally, the elements in M-th chunk will have 2 pointers: one for the previous and one for the next chunk. Then I would split my string (that I am about to insert) into chunks of M bytes each and then store them in M-th vector as a linked list. The last chunk with possibly less than M bytes I would store in the appropriate other vector. When removing a string, I would remove all its chunks from vectors and then reallocate lingering chunks and reconnect them so that new vectors constitute from consecutive chunks, i.e. don't have holes.

This idea satisfies my needs except its converging efficiency. Additionally, there comes the cost of M separate vectors which can't be ignored in computers.

Is there any other already existing idea which explains how to build this structure?

Comment: Are your objects strings? Do they exist over a finite alphabet, whose size is much smaller than the total number of strings? If so, even if there aren't common morphemes, a trie will still be very efficient. Your question is rather nonspecific about what your objects are and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Welbog Please, I was very specific. Tries are out of consideration because Tries save every character in a structure. That is many extra bytes PER BYTE of a string. That is not acceptable. My strings exist over 256 values of a byte. So yes, it is finite.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding what specifically you’re trying to support. What operations does the data structure need to be able to do? Can you give more details about the use case?